# Overlay line graph on stacked bar in d3.js when x-axis is strings

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I'm having an issue adding a line graph in svg, partially I think because my x-axis is using months as strings. I was wondering if there was a way to incorporate the line even when I don't have standard date.

```
       function barStack(d) {
            var l = d[0].length
            while (l--) {
                var posBase = 0, negBase = 0;
                d.forEach(function(d) {
                    d=d[l]
                    d.size = Math.abs(d.y)
                    if (d.y<0)  {
                        d.y0 = negBase
                        negBase-=d.size
                    } else
                    { 
                        d.y0 = posBase = posBase + d.size
                    } 
                })
            }
            d.extent= d3.extent(d3.merge(d3.merge(d.map(function(e) { return e.map(function(f) { return [f.y0,f.y0-f.size]})}))))
            return d
        }
        //assets and debts
        var data = [[{y:3000},{y:2000},{y:2500},{y:1000},{y:3000},{y:5000}],
                    [{y:-700},{y:-300},{y:-1000},{y:-500},{y:-1100},{y:-2000}]]
        //debt to assets
        var ratio = []
        for (var i = 0; i<data[0].length; i++){
            ratio.push(data[1][i]/data[0][i]*-1);
        }
        Date.prototype.monthNames = [
            "January", "February", "March",
            "April", "May", "June",
            "July", "August", "September",
            "October", "November", "December"];
        Date.prototype.getMonthName = function() {
            return this.monthNames[this.getMonth()];
        };
        // creates array of previous 6 months
        var d = new Date();
        var n = d.getMonth();
        var last_6_months = [];
        for(var i=data[0].length; i>0; i--){
            temp_month = d;
            temp_month.setMonth(n - i);
            last_6_months.push(temp_month.getMonthName());
        }
        //combine ratio and dates to use in svg line
        var data1 = []
        for(var i=0; i<data[0].length; i++){
            var object = {}
            object.month = last_6_months[i]
            object.ratio = ratio[i]
            data1.push(object)
        }
        var  h=500
        ,w=500
        ,margin=40
        ,color = d3.scale.category10()

        ,x = d3.scale.ordinal()
            .domain(last_6_months)
            .rangeRoundBands([margin,w-margin], .1)

        ,y = d3.scale.linear()
            .range([h-margin,0+margin])


        ,xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom").tickSize(6, 0)
        ,yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left")

        //variables used in line graph
        ,y1 = d3.scale.linear()
                .range([h-margin,0+margin])
        ,yAxisRight = d3.svg.axis().scale(y1).orient("right");
        ,valueline = d3.svg.line()
                        .x(function(d) { return x(d.month); })
                        .y(function(d) { return y1(d.ratio); })
                        .interpolate("linear");
        y1.domain(ratio.extent)            


        barStack(data)
        y.domain(data.extent)
        svg = d3.select("body")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("height",h)
                .attr("width",w)

        svg.selectAll(".series").data(data)
            .enter().append("g").classed("series",true).style("fill", function(d,i) { return color(i)})
            .selectAll("rect").data(Object)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("x",function(d,i) { return x(x.domain()[i])})
            .attr("y",function(d) { return y(d.y0)})
            .attr("height",function(d) { return y(0)-y(d.size)})
            .attr("width",x.rangeBand())

        //line ratio
        svg.data(data1).enter().append("path")  
             .attr("class", "line")
             .attr("d", valueline(data1));

        svg.append("g").attr("class","axis x").attr("transform","translate (0 "+y(0)+")").call(xAxis)
        svg.append("g").attr("class","axis y").attr("transform","translate ("+x(margin)+" 0)").call(yAxis)

        //axis for ratio
        svg.append("g").attr("class", "axis y").attr("transform", "translate(" + x(margin) + " 0)").style("fill", "red").call(yAxisRight);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `d3.svg.line` functions have no problem dealing with an ordinal scale.  However, normally you would use the [`ordinal.rangePoints()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Ordinal-Scales#wiki-ordinal_rangePoints) method when you just want the points for a line.  That way, the point on the line would match up with the point on the axis.

Since you're using the `ordinal.rangeBands()` in order to position your bar chart, you need to specify that you want the point for the line to be in the middle of the bar.  You can do that in the x-accessor function of the `d3.svg.line` object:

```
valueline = d3.svg.line()
              .x(function(d) { return x(d.month) + x.rangeBand()/2; })
              .y(function(d) { return y1(d.ratio); })
              .interpolate("linear");
```

If you're still having problems, try to put together a simplified working example, or at least post more specific details of the problem.